# Send an Email from unix with multiple files row count and size

Tags: email, unix

I'm new to Unix environment, I have a requirement where i have to send an email to the users with 3 files row count, size and date among multiple files in the directory. Files will be generated every month so every month mail has to be sent after files generation.

here is the example,

target directoy : /work/directory
List of files under the directory:

month_f1.txt

month_f2.txt

month_f3.txt

old_month_f1.txt

old_month_f2.txt

Email should be:

Hi All,

PFB file details.

filename        rowcount    size

month_f1.txt    100         20567

month_f2.txt    200         40567

month_f3.txt    300         60567

Thanks in advance!!

~Sri

Comment: It is not quite clear what you exactly want. Illustrating your problem with an example and describing what kind of solution you are looking for may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email from Unix with 3 files row count, size and date among 10 files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756204/how-to-send-an-email-from-unix-with-3-files-row-count-size-and-date-among-10-fi)