# How to send an email from Unix with 3 files row count, size and date among 10 files

Tags: email, unix

I'm in a requirement where i have to send an email to the users with 3 files row count, size and date among multiple files in a directory. Files will be generated every month so every month mail has to be sent after files generation.

Target directoy : `/work/directory`

List of files under the directory:

```
month_f1.txt    
month_f2.txt    
month_f3.txt    
old_month_f1.txt    
old_month_f2.txt
```

Email should be sent like below with files details:

```
Hi All,

PFB file details.    
---------------------------------
|filename       |rowcount |size  |  
---------------------------------
|month_f1.txt   |100      |20567 |  
|month_f2.txt   |200      |40567 |   
|month_f3.txt   |300      |60567 |
---------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm not fully aware of Unix code, so not tried. I know how to send a single file row count, size and date, but not sure how to read multiple files row count and size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much refactored Awk script to do everything in one go.

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "Subject: Numbers for this month\n";
        print "Hi All,\n\nPFB file details\n"
        print "----------------------------------"
        print "|filename       |rowcount |size  |"
        print "----------------------------------" }
    { bytes[FILENAME] += length($0)+1; ++lines[FILENAME] }
    END { for (j=1; j<ARGC; ++j)
        printf("|%-15s|%9i|%6i|\n", ARGV[j], lines[ARGV[j]], bytes[ARGV[j]])
        print "----------------------------------" }' /work/directory/file* | 
sendmail email@domain.com
```

`FILENAME` is a built-in Awk variable with the file name of the currently open file, and `ARGV` is the list of file name arguments.  The rest should be fairly obvious; we add the length of the current line (plus one for the terminating newline, which is stripped by Awk) to the byte count for this file, and increase the line count.  When we are done, we print the accumulated numbers.

Comment: of course, doing everying in awk is nicer. Can you explain what the lines with `FNR==1..` and the following lines are doing?

Comment: I still don't understand how this works. I understand that whole block loops over `/work/directory/file*`, `BEGIN` is only done before the first file and `END` after the last file. The `FNR==1` and the line below are done for every file. But where does it loop through the file counting the lines? I'd expect a for loop through the file `FILENAME`

Comment: Awk loops over every line in every input file by design.  You use that in your own script as well to loop over the output from `wc`.

Comment: aha, and `FNR==1 { files[++i] = FILENAME }` is only executed on first line of the input?

Comment: Actually I removed the `FNR` and now loop over `ARGV` directly.  I wasn't sure it was portable, but it seems that it is.

Comment: thank you for the awk primer, indeed with `argv` it is a lot nicer. And generally awk looks like a very good fit for the job -> upvoted

Comment: Thanks much Tripleee, i know it takes time for me to understand :D , Once again Thank you!!!

Doubt: When i received email from the above code, the list of users in TO list are not visible, seems those are in BCC. How to bring those TO list

Comment: Print the headers you want in the same place you print the Subject: header.  Like `BEGIN { print "Subject: foo"; print "From: myself <address@example.net>"; print "To: users, comma, separated"; print; print "Hello world etc etc" }` -- note that there needs to be an empty line between the headers and the message itself.

Comment: To use the `To:` header in the message, use `sendmail -t` so you don't have to list the recipients twice.

Comment: Thank you Tripleee, I'm extremely sorry why i cant upvote your answer though I have been trying so.

Comment: No worries; maybe come back when you can (-:

Comment: When i click on Upvote button, it shows

'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score' not sure what it is as I'm new here

Comment: Yeah, you can come back when you have the 15 rep.  I *think* your vote here will have registered then but I'm not sure.

Comment: @tripleee, hansaplast
I'm trying to change the filename while displaying, but not able to achieve with IF then ELSE stmt, can u pls help me here if I'm wrong with below change

'for (j=1; j<ARGC; ++j)
if [ ARGV[j] = "abcd" ] then
 fname= "bcda"
 else 
 fname= "cdab"
 fi
 printf("|%-15s|%9i|%6i|\n", $fname, lines[ARGV[j]], bytes[ARGV[j]]'

Comment: You want `fname` not `$fname`.  The dollar sign indicates access to an input field in Awk.  Also you need braces around the block if you intend the `for` loop to execute a block of multiple statements.  (Braces are optional when there is a single statement in the block.)

Answer (score 1):

To send out a stat mail about *all files* in `work/directory/` this shell script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Subject: Stats of 3 files\n\nHi All,\n\nPFB file details" > /tmp/stats_mail.txt
printf "%40s %8s %8s\n" filename rowcount size >> /tmp/stats_mail.txt
for file in "/work/directory/file1" "/work/directory/file2" "/work/directory/file3"; do
  cnt=`wc $file | awk {'print $1" "$3'}`;
  cnt_line=$(echo $cnt | cut -f1 -d" ")
  cnt_size=$(echo $cnt | cut -f2 -d" ")
  printf "%40s %8s %8s\n" $file $cnt_line $cnt_size >> /tmp/stats_mail.txt
done
sendmail "email@domain.com" < /tmp/stats_mail.txt
rm /tmp/stats_mail.txt
```

This assumes you have `sendmail` set up.

Depending on the length of filenames, size and row count, you might need to tweak the column sizes (`%40s` and `%8s`, they appear both in the header and then in the `while` loop)

Here is a sample output:

```
Subject: Stats of 3 files

Hi All,

PFB file details

                             filename rowcount     size
/var/tmp/file1.txt                       72229  6667249
/var/tmp/file2.txt                       44299  4343903
```

Comment: Thank you for the details Hansaplast!!
I want specifically three file details only to be on email instead of all files in the directory.

Suppose file1, file2...file10 are there, among that i want only file2, file5, and file8 details only.

Comment: @Srini I changed my code so you can specify which files you want to be listed

Comment: Thank you so much Hans!! I will use it and let you know the details

Comment: @Srini I fixed some issues with the script. Be sure to use the latest version

Comment: Thanks for the details but is there any chance to edit how to get the details in tabular format so that it would be high in readability. Please check the output details in your post. Thanks

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer. Can you post the current output into gist.github.com and post the link here? So I can have a look what's screwed there

Comment: @Srini ping in case you didn't get a notification for the comment above

Comment: Hasaplast, I have edited the output format in my post above, please check and get back to me, Thank you!!

Comment: @Srini why don't you try adding this yourself? With the solution I gave you it's just a matter of adapting some strings in the bash script, you already have the basic layout

Comment: The temp file is unnecessary and inelegant, you can just `for blah blah; do blah blah; done | sendmail`

Comment: @tripleee I agree. I first had it with the pipe, but then I added the echo and printf at the top. How would you elegantly make the whole block pipe into sendmail?

Comment: If you are using Awk anyway, you want to avoid the `echo | cut` etc.  See the answer I posted just now.

Comment: @Srini try the code below by tripleee, it already has the right markup